# Image not on SD Card

Tags: android

I've got a camera application and when I take a picture the image is stored. However I cannot see it on the SD Card until I reboot the device.

Any ideas why? Also when I view the image as a bitmap in my activity (After restarting) the picture is flipped the wrong way around. Any ideas about that?

**My code is as follows:**

```
Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try
    {
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
      fileUrl = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bm, "LastTaken", "Picture");

      if(fileUrl == null)
      {
        Log.d("Still", "Image Insert Failed");
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        picUri = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, picUri));
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Log.d("Picture", "Error Picture: ", e);
    }
    camera.startPreview();
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried a different file explorer to look at the picture?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this was a long time ago. The API was seriously updated after 1.6 to make life far easier!

Comment: Haha. Sorry. I usually browse questions by "newest", but apparently failed to do that. I wouldn't have usually commented on a 2 year old post because it is... well, pointless. And I failed to look at the age before commenting.